# Any JMockit like framework for .net which can even mock static classes, private methods, etc

Tags: .net, testing, mocking

I used JMockit - http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/ for mocking out stuffs while doing unit testing in java. Unlike other frameworks it is on top of JVM byte code not on instrumentation libraries. It can mock static classes, methods even private fields and methods too.

Require similar kind of framework for .net, is there any ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few of them:

TypeMock's [Isolator .NET](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page)

> Mock and fake the unmockable (including statics, non-public, sealed)

Telerik's [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx)

> You can fake objects like non-virtual methods, sealed classes and
>   static methods and classes, non-public members and types, features
>   often not available in free mocking frameworks.

But both of them are commercial products.

I haven't used it but you also can have a look on [Pex and Mole](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/pex-and-moles-isolation-and-white-box-unit-testing-for-net/) it's a Microsoft research project to help unit testing:

> Moles allows to replace any .NET method with a delegate. Moles
>   supports unit testing by providing isolation by way of detours and
>   stubs. The Moles framework is provided with Pex, or can be installed
>   by itself as a Microsoft Visual Studio add-in.

I don't know any another free "mock everything" framework for .NET.